# bash: Escape multiple parameters that are read from file

Tags: bash, escaping

I have a file which contains URLs, one in each line. These URLs may contain spaces or other hazardous elements. I want to call a program with these urls, all of them at once.

`urls.txt`:

```
ptoto://domain/maybe with spaces & stuff 1
ptoto://domain/maybe with spaces & stuff 2
ptoto://domain/maybe with spaces & stuff 3
```

I want transform files like this to a call like:

```
myCommand "ptoto://domain/maybe with spaces & stuff 1" "ptoto://domain/maybe with spaces & stuff 2" "ptoto://domain/maybe with spaces & stuff 3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
while read -r; do
    args+=("$REPLY")
done < textfile.txt
myCommand "${args[@]}"
```

Here, `$REPLY` is the default variable where `read` stores its result when no variable name is prompted. we use an array to store each line, and the double quotes forces to keep spaces & other characters.

`"${args[@]}"` display each element of the array

Comment: Not good: `myCommand` got 1 parameter (instead of 3), its value was `"ptoto://domain/maybe with spaces & stuff 1" "ptoto://domain/maybe with spaces & stuff 2" "ptoto://domain/maybe with spaces & stuff 3"`

Comment: Ok, you'll have to use an array. I'll edit my answer in a minute.

Comment: 3 parameters now, but each parameter value has `"` (quotation marks) at the beginning and at the end. My testing tool `printParams.sh`: `echo "$#"; for var in "$@"; do echo "$var"; done`

Comment: Test prog written in C gives same result: `int main(int argc, char **argv){ for(int i=1; i<argc; ++i) printf("%s\n",argv[i]); return 0; }`

Comment: Ok, sorry it was so tedious, I don't have a shell to test my code before posting. You should just remove the `\"` in the array construction (I edited the answer)